# Input data into two strings

Tags: c++, string

Let's say we have an input stream for c++. It contains a list of books with their release dates and then name. A line in the input data looks something like this.

```
 Book title here        Month Day, Year
```

I want to put the book title in one string, and then the year the book was released on in another string. Such that `string foo = Book title here ;` and that `string bar = Month Day, Year;` But if you simply do `data >> string` it will only go up to the next whitespace. In which foo would be `foo = Month` and bar being `bar = Day,`. Getline gets the whole line in which foo would become `foo = Month Day, Year    Book title here`and bar being either the next line or who knows what.

How exactly would I go about this?

Comment: can you please put your code what you try with your idea.

Comment: To begin with, I suggest you read the full line. Then go backwards over the string, passing, the year, the day and the month. Then you know where the book title ends.

Comment: Regex might be useful here (but it has its own learning curve).

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of work, it's better to use a [Comma-Separated Value](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values), in which each element to read is separated by a symbol you choose, e.g `';'`.

```
Book title here;Month Day, Year
```

Then you can read your file using

```
std::string title, date;

std::getline(yourFile, title, ';');
std::getline(yourFile, date);
```

The third parameter of `getline()` specifies the symbol to use as string separator.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

When a line-based format becomes to complex to be parsed start to finish, it's best to pre-read the whole line and then analyze the line contents in more detail.

This seems to be the case for your question, since you can't know whether you read part of the book title or the book date, unless there is a defined delimiter or you reached the end of line. Consider the following example  lines:

```
"Book Horror Story September 11, 2001"
"Book Horror Story September 11, 2001 October 12, 2019"
```

If you parse this text left-right, you can't know whether "September 11, 2001" is part of the title or part of the date, until you reach the end of line.

So you start with `std::getline` to read a whole line into a string and then you extract the details from each line. You can do it by manually parsing the line right-to-left as @Someprogrammerdude commented, by developing a regular expression that accepts the line format or use any other appropriate technique.